# Find the directional derivative of a function along the curve.

Tags: derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative, parametrization

**Question:** 
Find the directional derivative of f=x^2·y·z^3 along the curve x = e^-u; y = 2 sin u + 1; z = u - cos u at the point P where u = 0

**My working:**

At u=0, x=1, y=1, z=-1 so let **u** = (1,1,-1).

Know that D_**u** f(**x**) = ∇f(**x**) · **u** = (2x·y·z^3, x^2·z^3, 3x^2·y·z^3) · (1,1,-1) =  (2x·y·z^3, x^2·z^3, -3x^2·y·z^2).

At u=0,  **x**=(1,1,-1) so D_**u** f(**x**)=(2·1·1·-1, 1·-1, -3·1·1·1)=(-2,-1,-3)

However, I'm not sure if this is correct as I don't know whether I'm meant to substitute **u** into f to find the derivative at a specific point or not?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x(u+h),y(u+h),z(u+h))-f(x(u),y(u),z(u))}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left(f_x\dfrac{dx}{du}+f_y\dfrac{dy}{du}+f_z\dfrac{dz}{du}\right)h}h
\\=\nabla f\cdot\left(\dfrac{dx}{du},\dfrac{dy}{du},\dfrac{dz}{du}\right).$$